# Lock in Singleton + Builder pattern in ASP.NET. Make builder pattern safe threaded

Tags: asp.net, .net, thread-safety, singleton, builder

I am facing a strange situation that is driving me crazy.
I have a Class **MyApplication.cs**

```
public class MyApplication 
{
    private static volatile MyApplication _instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private Logger logger=new Logger();

    static public MyApplication Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new MyApplication ();
                }
            }
            return _instance;

        }

      public void Load(){
         logger.setId("100").setMessage("Load succesful").Write();
      }


}
```

It has a singleton pattern.

Also  I have a **Logger.cs** class with Builder pattern:

```
    public class Logger
    {
         private string Id="NOT_SET";
         private string Message;

         public Logger setId(int id){
             this.Id=id;
         }
         public Logger setMessage(string message){
             this.Message=message;
         }
         public void Write(){
              if(Id="NOT_SET"){
                throw Exception("NOT SET EXCEPCION");  
              }
              //write output staff
         }
```

}

**Problem**: Every page load of my ASP.NET app, the MyApplication Load() method gets called. So a new Logger object is created every request.

```
Page_load(){
   MyApplication.Instance.Load();
}
```

The fact is that i am getting sometimes the NOT_SET_EXCEPTION.
It might be for some concurrent accesing to the Logger variable in MyApplication cause it gets reseted by a reason i cannot understand.

- What do you think?
- How can i make safe threaded the Logger variable?
- Is a bad idea to use builder patter in this case?

It would be desirable to lock the creational procces until it ends, because if not logger variable gets modified from different threads..
Please help

Comment: You are using the pattern in the wrong way! You are "setting it up" (with the `Load`) every time the page is created. The Load should be in the `MyApplication Instance` getter, when it is instantiated

Comment: And you aren't using the Builder pattern... Where is the `LoggerBuilder`?

Comment: I don´t want to call Log actions only from the getter method, also from other places. So placing the Load() in the getter not works for my solution. What should i do?

Comment: Ok... But you are mixing the `Logger` with the `Message`. The `Logger` "writes" "`Message`s". To build a `Message` you can use the `Builder` pattern, and have a `MessageBuilder`. The Logger can have a `Write(Message message)` instance method. So in the `Load()` method you would have: `logger.Write(new MessageBuilder().setId(...).setMessage(...).ToMessage()`)

Comment: see the answer, does it fit to you?

Answer (score 0):

As xanatos suggested i created a new class LoggBuilder() , also the thread safe code is now inside a lock, so the methods

- Id()
- Message()
- Write()

  are executed at once.

  ```
  public class LoggerBuilder
  {
  private static object syncRoot = new Object();

  Logger logger;
  int eventId;
  string message;


  public LoggerBuilder(Logger logger)
  {
      this.logger = logger;
  }

  public LoggerBuilder EventId(int EventId)
  {
      this.eventId = EventId;
      return this;
  }


  public LoggerBuilder Message(string Message)
  {
      this.message = Message;
      return this;
  }


  public void Write()
  {
      lock (syncRoot)
      {
          logger.EventId(this.eventId);
          logger.Message(this.message);
          logger.Write();
      }
  }
  ```

  }
  }